# $100-$200 monitor with displayport daisy chaining

Tags: monitors, display-port

I don't need a super fancy monitor, but I would like it to support displayport daisy chaining. All the monitors I can find with this feature are >$300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Dell U2417H that supports DP daisy chaining.  You can find used monitors on eBay for ~$120.  Besides supporting DP daisy changing it is a very good monitor.  The picture quality is great and it even has a built in USB 3.0 hub for easy access to your USB ports.

Comment: haha, that is almost exactly the monitor I'm borrowing that led me to ask this question (I have the U2419H) and I agree it's pretty great. Thanks for the Ebay suggestion, I'll check it out!

Comment: Sure enough! There were used but otherwise complete and working U2417Hs on ebay for $94 (under 1/3rd of the new price!). I got two of them for 70% of what a single new one would cost. Absolute steal. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem! Glad you found what you needed :)